In WPF, how do I animate several objects along a single path so they "chase" each other?
I have several objects laid out along a circle in a custom panel.  All available positions on the circle are captured in a list of points, called _Positions.  Right now, when I scroll items, they just increment to the next position in the list.
I'd like to animate this motion.  To reiterate, I have several objects moving between two sets of well-defined points along a circular path.  I just have no clue where to start.
I'm using WPF, and I want the panel to hold the animation ideally, so I need to code it in C#.  This seems like something that should be able to be done easily, but I'm really new to the idea of animation.
NOTE: Right now, I have about 20 objects.  That said, the number of objects depends on the number of children of the panel, and I have a project waiting that needs about 150 of them.  Ideally, I'd like to keep the resource use light.
NOTE 2: In the future, I will definitely consider virtualization and only animating visible objects, but for now, I just want to figure out how to create the animation in general.  Help please!

How to: Animate an Object Along a Path (Matrix Animation)

Sounds like you want an ellipse geometry for your circle.

Using "StoryBoards", you can animate an object along a path. To "chase", use "instances" of the same StoryBoard; but with different "start times"; running "forever". https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/graphics-multimedia/how-to-animate-an-object-along-a-path-double-animation?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8
